# Dual Monitor-Is there a way to make one monitor have 1 background the same, and the other one rotate

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor set-up for my bedroom. And i was wondering- is there a way to make it so that one monitor's background stay's one set image, and the other one rotates through multiple photo's (Like window's 7 already can do)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Windows supports this by default, but there's an awesome multi-monitor program called [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). There's a relatively sophisticated Wallpaper Settings menu where you can set each monitor's wallpaper source individually. Right now, I'm doing exactly what you're inquiring about using it: I've set 1 monitor to a static image and another monitor to rotate through a folder.

It has a Free and Premium version.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pleasant, but you can make a set of images which are the size of your 2 monitors combined. On the left hand side you would always have the same image and on the right you would have different images. Then set the background images to tile.

I'm not sure if this is possible with monitors running at different resolutions - it might take a little more work.